# How to know p12 file has private key or not?

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

I got this error in Xcode:

> Missing private key for signing certificate.

Though in Keychain Assistant I can open p12 and see there is something inside. Isn't that the private key?

[image]

[image]

Comment: And where is your public key? Do you have a development certificated installed in a keychain? Did you log in your dev account in xCode preference? Downloaded all profiles from there?

Comment: p12 and mobil provision belongs to our partner. I do not belong to their Apple Development program, I do not have access to id.. They sent us to make them an IPA, but I am not sure why Xcode refuse p12.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, that is the private key. There's one more thing you should check. The signing certificate has to be correct in two places:

1. In the provisioning profile. The provisioning profile also names which certificate to use. Head to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profile` and locate the PP that Xcode is using. Then press the spacebar to preview it. The serial number listed in there should match the one in Keychain Access. It's possible you have an older version with a different private key but same name.
2. In Xcode build settings. That's the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY build setting in your second screenshot. Try picking this value manually from the "Certificates in Keychain" option as opposed to the automatic options.